# UIkit Sortable mouse position while dragging

Tags: uikit, getuikit

I'm trying to listen to mousemove or drag events when dragging a sortable item. I need to know the mouse position while dragging. Here is an example.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bribar/3kh9b5xv)

```
document.addEventListener('drag', (e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please post your attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Did you check out the jsfiddle? I tried consoling out a few different event listeners. None of them work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bribar/3kh9b5xv/